# Idiomatic python - property or method?

Tags: python, django

I have a django model class that maintains state as a simple property. I have added a couple of helper properties to the class to access aggregate states - e.g. `is_live` returns false if the state is any one of `['closed', 'expired', 'deleted']` etc.

As a result of this my model has a collection of is_ properties, that do very simple lookups on internal properties of the object.

I now want to add a new property, `is_complete` - which is semantically the same as all the other properties - a boolean check on the state of the object - however, this check involves loading up dependent (one-to-many) child objects, checking their state and reporting back based on the results - i.e. this property actually does some (more than one) database query, and processes the results.

So, is it still valid to model as a property (using the `@property` decorator), or should I instead forego the decorator and leave it as a method?

Pro of using a property is that it's semantically consistent with all the other `is_` properties.

Pro of using a method is that it indicates to other developers that this is something that has a more complex implementation, and so should be used sparingly (i.e. not inside a `for..` loop).

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):

    state = CharField(default='new')

    @property
    def is_open(self):
        # this is a simple lookup, so makes sense as a property
        return self.state in ['new', 'open', 'sent']

    def is_complete(self):
        # this is a complex database activity, but semantically correct
        related_objects = self.do_complicated_database_lookup()
        return len(related_objects)==0
```

EDIT: I come from a .NET background originally, where the split is admirably defined by Jeff Atwood as

> "if there's any chance at all that code could spawn an hourglass, it definitely should be a method."

EDIT 2: slight update to the question - would it be a problem to have it as a method, called `is_complete`, so that there are mixed properties and methods with similar names - or is that just confusing?

So - it would look something like this:

```
>>> m = MyModel()
>>> m.is_live
True
>>> m.is_complete()
False
```

Comment: I think it still makes sense. Can you cache the result as `self._is_complete` or is this computed multiple times? Can you be running the computation in the background or is computation only valid when the property is assessed?

Comment: @JaceBrowning: I had exactly the same idea (please see my answer). I assumed this is okay (if not, it can always be cleared).

Comment: @Tadeck: no worries. I don't know enough about `django` to know if this application makes sense.

Comment: The easy way out of this dilemma is to rename `is_complete` to `check_completeness`. Ugly, but at least it signals clearly that an expensive check is going to be performed.

Comment: @larsmans - I agree - I could do that, however the "is_" name is semantically meaningful and consistent - so I really want to keep that - as the rest of the API uses that nomenclature.

Comment: @HugoRodger-Brown: in any case, it's a matter of taste as far as I can tell. Unless you need properties for, say, Jinja compatibility, there's no technical reason for or against either option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is okay to do that, especially if you will use the following pattern:

```
class SomeClass(models.Model):
    @property
    def is_complete(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_is_complete'):
            related_objects = self.do_complicated_database_lookup()
            self._is_complete = len(related_objects) == 0
        return self._is_complete
```

Just remember that it "caches" the results, so first execution does calculation, but subsequent use existing results.

Comment: Thanks @tadeck - I think this is a valid approach, but on reflection what I should have asked is whether having mixed properties and methods (with same naming convention - see question edit 2)?

Comment: @HugoRodger-Brown: Pep8 mentions that both methods and instance variables us `underscore_seperate_names`, so yes it's absolutely fine. As both the method and variable return a boolean, `is_` is what I'd expect the prefix to be as well.

Comment: @TyrantWave: I generally agree. Plus, good (or average) IDEs are able to tell when something is a property, a method, or some other attribute, and display it properly. Additionally, one could expect `check_` methods to either not return anything (technically: `None`), or accept a callback that will then be passed the result (in case of event-based approach). But PEP8 also states: "_Consistency within a project is more important. Consistency within one module or function is most important._". So it is better to have consistent library, than to follow other people's expectations.